# Solving a system of nonlinear equations without calculator

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Solve, for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$\begin{cases} 2^x + 3^y = 72\\ 2^y + 3^x = 108 \end{cases}$$

**Attempt**: I could write the following:
From the second equation $$y=\frac{\ln (108-{{3}^{x}})}{\ln 2}=\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}\ln (108-{{3}^{x}})$$ and replacing in the first equation we get: $${{2}^{x}}+{{(108-{{3}^{x}})}^{\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}}}=72$$
The LHS is monotonically decreasing, so we have only one solution, and indeed $x=4,150...$ is a solution (using WA).

How could I solve it without using a calculator?

Comment: I may be missing something but how’d you get the second equality for $y$? The ln$3$ over the ln$2$..

Comment: @Assandra Lakal I did an edit but did not correct your math, which you should check.

Comment: Just an idea, may help you to notice that $72=2^3 3^2$ and $108=2^2 3^3$ which may not be a coincidence. It's easy to get a RHS equal to zero, but then trying to equate coefficients / exponents didn't work for me so far... still thinking about it...

Comment: Your system of equations seems wrong to me. I think, the correct equation should be $$\begin{cases}2^x\cdot 3^y=72\\ 2^y\cdot 3^x=108\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

*I cheated since I used my phone.*

From the first equation
$$2^x+3^y=72 \quad \implies \quad y=\frac{\log \left(72-2^x\right)}{\log (3)}$$ Replace in the second equation and define the recursion
$$x=\frac 1 {\log(3)}\,\log \left(108-2^{\frac{\log \left(72-2^{x}\right)}{\log(3)}}\right) $$

$$x_0=0 \implies x_1=4.12845\implies x_2=4.15026\implies x_3=4.15062$$

But, if we do it using the other way
$$2^y+3^x=108 \quad \implies \quad y=\frac{\log \left(108-3^x\right)}{\log (2)}$$
$$x=\frac 1 {\log(2)}\,\log \left(72-3^{\frac{\log \left(108-3^{x}\right)}{\log   (2)}}\right)$$
$$x_0=0 \implies x_1=10.6205 + 4.53236\,i \qquad\color{red}{ \text{bad news}}$$

Comment: IMO, the system of equation seems wrong to me . I think that, the correct system of equation should be $$\begin{cases}2^x\cdot 3^y=72\\ 2^y\cdot 3^x=108\end{cases}$$

Comment: @lonestudent. You may be right and this would be simple

Comment: Closed forms usually don't exist except for class problems.